# How to define settable lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a record type in my Haskell code to which I want to define a lens that can be used as a getter and as a setter. The code looks like this:

```
data Players = Players { _white :: Player
                       , _black :: Player
                       } deriving (Show, Eq)
makeLenses ''Players
_byColor :: Color -> Players -> Player
_byColor White = _white
_byColor Black = _black
byColor col = to (_byColor col)
```

`Players` is a record holding the white and the black player. I want to be able to get a player by color in a lens fashion. E.g.

```
players ^. byColor White . hp  -- Access health-points of player
```

However, I also want to be able to set a property of a player chosen by color. E.g. within a state-monad holding a `Game` record with a `_players` field.

```
let current = White
players . byColor current . hp %= (-1)
```

With my current definition of `byColor` however the code fails to compile with the following error message:

```
No instance for (Contravariant Identity)
  arising from a use of `byColor'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Contravariant Identity)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `to` combinator only makes a getter, you haven't defined a full lens.  However, defining the full lens is pretty straightforward, you just need to return the correct lens based on the color passed in:

```
byColor :: Color -> Lens' Players Player
byColor White = white
byColor Black = black
```

Comment: Thanks, that's far easier than I thought. Sorry, if this was a stupid question. I have to admit that I find the documentation of lens a little bit difficult to use.

Comment: @Lemming Trust me when I say that I still sometimes struggle with the lens library and its documentation.  At least it has documentation, but it's definitely harder to follow the types than with other libraries.